I have 2 sealed bags but can’t seem to figure out what set
I have bag 2 which is 606R1 and bag 5 which is 721R1 the QR code comes up with 617-2089 (bag 2) and 617-2091 (bag 5).

Those numbers relate more to the bags than the set.

These numbers are irrelevant. Please add clear pictures of your bags.

Hi Heidi and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take a look at the method described in Henrik's comment and let us know if you have any issues following it. You can also take the [tour] or check the [help] pages to learn more about the site and community here. Play well!
